# Build custom Docker microsoft dotnet image with NuGet packages already downloaded

Tags: docker, nuget, .net-core

I'm currently building some applications that rely on .net core, and are hosted inside a Docker-container.

However this eats up quite some disk space, because each application needs to download and install its dependencies again. But disk space isn't even my main concern. I'm also very interested in continuous deployment, so it's important to have a very fast build-process.

Currently quite some build time is lost on the following:

```
log  : Installing System.Reflection.Emit 4.0.1.

log  : Installing System.Reflection.TypeExtensions 4.1.0.
```

and so on. So I thought, I can make use of the Docker-union-file-system, and create a custom base-image (myowndotnetimage:1.1.0), and use this for all my containers:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1.0-sdk-projectjson

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install npm -y

RUN npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
RUN npm install npm -g
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

However now I was wondering, if there is an efficient way to install some NuGet packages inside my base-Docker-image. So I'm searching for something like

```
dotnet install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
```

That I can run inside my Dockerfile, for my base-image. An alternative I'm concidering, is to mount the packages-directory as a volume. But I would rather avoid this.

Comment: Not an expert in Windows docker by any means, but you should be able to cache the intermediate layers of the image for subsequent builds.  This will speed things up greatly if in your docker file you put the things that change the least at the top (so the result can be cached).  Typically I would put system dependencies first, then code dependencies, then actual code components last.

Comment: .net core is cross-platform now, so not windows-specific. This is indeed something I'm trying to do, unfortunately the dependencies are inside a project.json which is part of my code. Could this work if I copy project.json as a seperate add-command?

Comment: Are you including `dotnet restore` as a command in the dockerfile?

Comment: Mhtsbt, Yes, that's typically what I do.  Copy the file (s) you need for dependency resolution, then the rest.  This works great with the languages I've used (Python, Ruby, Js, c) so hopefully it will work great for your language too.

Comment: That indeed solves the performance-issue. @NateBarbettini yes I am